Proving the series $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \big( (-1)^n (1-x)x^n \big)$ uniformly converges in $[0,1]$
I am trying to prove the following series of functions uniformly converges in $[0,1]$:
$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \big( (-1)^n (1-x)x^n \big)$
I proved that the limit function is $f(x) = \frac{x^2-x}{1+x}$, and that the series converges in every point in the interval $[0,1]$.
I tried using Weierstrass' M-test, but without luck...
Dini's theorem doesn't hold either, because the functions themselves aren't non-negative for every $n$.
I turned to Cauchy's criterion, but I was able to reach only the following result:
for every $0<x<1$:
$\big| \sum_{k=n+1}^m (-1)^k(1-x)x^k \big| \le (1-x)\big| \sum_{k=n+1}^m (-x)^k \big| \le (1-x) \cdot \big( \frac{x^{n+1}(1-x^m)}{1-x} \big) = x^{n+1}(1-x^m)$
where $n,m$ come from the Cauchy criterion ($m>n>N$ $\implies$ $\big| \sum_{k=n+1}^m f_k(x) \big|<\varepsilon$ ).
How should I proceed? Assuming, of course, my hypothesis that the series does uniformly converge in $[0,1]$

Try the Supremum Test.

With  small change you can get bound  for $| \sum_{k=n+1}^m (-1)^k(1-x)x^k \big|$ by $\frac {1-x} {1+x} x^{n+1}$. You can easily make this $< \epsilon$ for $n$ large enough.

Let $a_n(x)=(1-x)x^n$ and $b_n(x)=(-1)^n$,
then, by
$$(1-x)x^n=\frac1n\cdot n(1-x)x^n\leq\frac1n\left(\frac{n(1-x)+nx}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}
=\frac1n\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}}
<\frac{1}{ne}\to0,$$
we know that the function sequences $\{a_n(x)\}$ is decreasing with respect to $n$ and uniformly convergent to $0$ on $[0,1]$. And for $b_n(x)=(-1)^n$,
we have
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^nb_n(x)\right|\leq1,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb N.$$
So by Dirichlet test, we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(x)b_n(x)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (1-x)x^n$$
is umifromly convergent on $[0,1]$.

Let $f_n(x)=(1-x)\sum_{k=1}^n(-x)^k.$ Then $f_n(x)={-x(1-x)\over 1+x}[1-(-x)^{n})]$ and $$ f(x)-f_n(x)={x(1-x)\over 1+x}(-x)^n$$ Hence $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\le (1-x)x^n.$ The maximal value of $(1-x)x^n$ is attained at $x_0=n/(n+1)$ and is less than $ 1/(n+1).$ Therefore $$|f(x)-f_n(x)|\le {1\over n+1}$$ The latter implies the uniform convergence of the series.
Remark A slightly weaker upper estimate of $(1-x)x^n$ can be proved in elementary way basing on the Bernoulli inequality. Let $0\le x<1.$ Then
$$(1-x)x^n={1-x\over (1+{1-x\over x})^n}\le {1-x\over n{1-x\over x}}={x\over n}\le {1\over n}$$
